при обработке выдает ошибку missing 1 required positional argument: 'send' сервера на fast api
абсолютно неважно что я ему кидаю что я возвращаю все равно такая ошибка

TypeError: FastAPI.call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'

вот код:
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Request
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import uvicorn
import json
import os
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def main():
    return {"message":"jghjhj"}



if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

использую питон 3.10

Какая версия FastAPI, какая версия uvicorn?

0.115.5 - fast api
0.32.1 - uvicorn

Код в том виде, в котором вы его написали, спокойно запускается без всяких ошибок. Добавьте полный вывод трассировки ошибки из консоли, для понимания причины проблемы

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 177, in handle_request
respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: FastAPI.call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'send'

Что у вас забыл gunicorn?

как показалось он просто подмодуль uvicorn или наооборот

Вообще никак не связанные и не совместимые вещи

тогда в душе ни чаю честно может быть мне стоит по другому запускать сервер?

Ну вот если просто взять и напрямую запустить показанный вами код без всяких там gunicorn'ов и прочего мусора, то всё прекрасно работает

так проблема в том что я его на сервере пускаю а там из-за моего недостаточного опыта дремучий лес так что если есть возможность сделать так как вы описали то я с радостью все поправлю

Любой нормальный сервер позволяет просто брать и напрямую запускать код. Если вам в этом что-то мешает — валите оттуда

простите в таком случае за глупый вопрос но как (я просто только начал)

Создавать асинхронные микросервисы, не умея запускать код — это сильно... Тогда это уже сюда — Книги и учебные ресурсы по Python
